# Pressure vacuum breaker noise

Tags: pressure, vacuum

I have a 6 zone sprinkler system about 6 years old. Two zones are just shrubs and bushes using dribblers. The other 4 have pop ups. When a pop up zone is runner the pressure vacuum breaker makes a rather rhythmic banging the can definitely be felt as well. Any guidance would be appreciated.